# getElementById is returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get basic text from an input in a form one called `name` and the other `email`. The `email` works, but `name` returns `undefined` and I cannot see any difference.
HTML:

```
<form id = "myForm" action = "" method = "post">
    <p id = "pName">Name: <input id = "iName" type = "text" name = "iName" placeholder="Name" /></p>
    <p id = "pEmail">Email: <input id = "iEmail" type = "email" name = "iEmail" placeholder="Email" /></p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
name = document.getElementById('iName');
email = document.getElementById('iEmail');
myConsole.innerHTML += "<p>name: " + name.value + "</p>" + "<p>email: " + email.value + "</p>";
```

Output:

> name: undefined
>
> email: none@none.non

Comment: there is no value in it... so it will give you undefined as a default value... its like an unassigned valued js variable.

Comment: The elements don't exist when they are queried? Try putting the code after the markup.

Comment: `getElementById` is not returning undefined, `value` is.

Comment: @Vache @nikhil `value` is always defined (event if it's just an empty string) for all input elements.

Comment: Did you declare name and email as variables; var name = etc.; var email = etc;  ?

Comment: @soktinpk That's a good point, but if `getElementById` had returned `undefined` shouldn't he get an error on `undefined.value` and not an "undefined" printed in his HTML? We might not see all the code here...

Comment: try it without calling the variable `name`. I do believe that is already a used variable in javascript and a keyword in HTML, you may be getting strange behavior because of it. Change the variable name to `vName` or something

Comment: @soktinpk there is no value attribute in the html., nothing in js code  either in the question... other than that if a js variable is declared but not assigned with a value and if i try to display the value of that variable it will display 'undefined'.

Comment: Yeah I didnt think about name being a reserved word, thank you. I am suprised Netbeans didnt show this as an error.

Comment: Two things FYI: a) `name` is not a reserved word (in JS), it's an existing global variable in browsers. b) `getElementById` is **never ever** returning `undefined`. It either returns a DOM element or `null`. So the fact that `name.value` returns `undefined` means that 1) `name` is *not* `null` or `undefined` and 2) `name` most likely doesn't have a property `value`. The next debugging step is to inspect the value of `name` and if it is anything else but a DOM element or `null`, then you know something is fishy with the variable name. Then you'd choose a different variable name, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I am trying to get better at JavaScript.  I know the basics of programming, but getting better.  The books I have been reading are helping, but this site is priceless.  Debugging isn't as easy wit js as it is with some other languages with a debugger like C# or Java.

Comment: I suggest you become familiar with the debugger in your browser. In Chrome, Firefox, and IE you can access the debugger by pressing F12 and selecting the sources/scripts/debugger tab. They're not quite as friendly as visual studio or eclipse debuggers but they are extremely useful when tackling issues like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "name" is returning the window context name.  If you define the variables as follows your script will work:

```
var myName = document.getElementById('iName'); 
var email = document.getElementById('iEmail'); 
myConsole.innerHTML += "<p>name: " + myName.value + "</p>" + "<p>email: " + email.value + "</p>";
```

Additionally, if you put your javascript in a function you can safely use `var name = ...` because your variables will become locally scoped.

Example here: http://jsbin.com/fugelipo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

`name` is already a declared member in the global scope. Declare your `name` variable in a narrower scope, or call it something else in your script.

```
function myFunction() {
    var name = document.getElementById('iName');
    var email = document.getElementById('iEmail');
    myConsole.innerHTML += "<p>name: " + name.value + "</p>" + "<p>email: " + email.value + "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Becuase you are declaring your variables without `var`, they are being created as global object properties, and there is already a property on the global object called `name`, and you cannot overwrite it (it won't error, it just won't do it)

something like the following should solve your issue

```
vName = document.getElementById('iName');
email = document.getElementById('iEmail');
myConsole.innerHTML += "<p>name: " + vName.value + "</p>" + "<p>email: " + email.value + "</p>";
```

You potentially wouldn't have had this error if you had defined your variable scope better. I can't see all of your code, but I would have assumed that your javascript was inside a function, then you should use `var` to declare your variables, otherwise it declares them as properties of the global object (the `window` object in web browser). So something like the following would have been better variable scope, as variables in javascript have function scoping, and would have preventing the clash with a global object property

```
function checkForm()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('iName');
    var email = document.getElementById('iEmail');
    myConsole.innerHTML += "<p>name: " + name.value + "</p>" + "<p>email: " + email.value + "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare "name" and "email" as variables.

> var name = document.getElementById('iName');
>
> var email = document.getElementById('iEmail');

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention that I declared var name, email in the global scope while this comes from a function when submit button is clicked

Answer (score -5):

Try name = document.getElementById(iName);

Comment: `iName` is not a declared variable

Comment: I didnt show all the code, just the relevant cod3. iName and iEmail should work exactly the same but only iEmail is unless there is something I am not seeing